# Efeito esmaecer com CSS3

Tags: css3, webkit

Estou tentando causar um efeito (sem sucesso) de esmaecer a imagem usando o seguinte código:

```css
@-webkit-keyframes fundo {    
    10%{
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(10%);
  -moz-filter: grayscale(10%);
  -ms-filter: grayscale(10%);
  -o-filter: grayscale(10%);
  filter: grayscale(10%);
  }     
   50%{      
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(50%);
  -moz-filter: grayscale(50%);
  -ms-filter: grayscale(50%);
  -o-filter: grayscale(50%);
  filter: grayscale(50%);
  }
   
   100%{
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%);
    }
img{
 -webkit-filter: fundo .5s infinite;
 -moz-filter: fundo .5s infinite;
 -ms-filter: fundo .5s infinite;
 -o-filter: fundo .5s infinite;
 filter: fundo .5s infinite;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/1">
```

Comment: Mas você quer esmaecer quando?! Após clicar? Passar o mouse por cima?ou naturalmente ao abrir a imagem?

Comment: Quero que fique naturalmente...@acklay

Answer (score 4):

Seu código esta faltando uma chave:

```
@-webkit-keyframes fundo {    
    10%{
        -webkit-filter: grayscale(10%);
        -moz-filter: grayscale(10%);
        -ms-filter: grayscale(10%);
        -o-filter: grayscale(10%);
        filter: grayscale(10%);
        }     
   50%{      
        -webkit-filter: grayscale(50%);
        -moz-filter: grayscale(50%);
        -ms-filter: grayscale(50%);
        -o-filter: grayscale(50%);
        filter: grayscale(50%);
        }

   100%{
        -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
        -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
        -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
        -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
        filter: grayscale(100%);
          }
}
img{
    -webkit-filter: fundo .5s infinite;
    -moz-filter: fundo .5s infinite;
    -ms-filter: fundo .5s infinite;
    -o-filter: fundo .5s infinite;
    filter: fundo .5s infinite;
}
```